# fs.writeFile creates file with -rw-r--r-- by default

Tags: node.js, fs

According to the [fs.writeFile documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), the default mode is 0o666. However, if I use `fs.writeFile` without specifying the mode option, my file is created with:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

My code is this:

```
  ...
  fs.writeFile(`public/${file}.json`, JSON.stringify(data), { encoding: "utf8" }, function (err) {
    if (err)
      return next(err);
    return res.json(null);
  });
```

My `umask` is 0002. If I `touch` a file in this folder from the shell with the same user id, I get `-rw-rw-r--`. This is an Ubuntu system.

Where did I go wrong? What should I specify for mode if I want `-rw-rw-r--`? I tried applying a value of 0o777 and it came out `-rwxr-xr-x`, which appears consistent but for group write access.

The folder in which the file resides has the `gid` bit set on the folder. Does this have impact?

Additional info: I have just found out that `fs.rename` changes a file's group access to no write even if the had originally has group write permission.

Comment: I seem to recall that you want to look at `umask`.

Comment: My `umask` is 0002. If I `touch` a file in the folder, it is created with `rw-rw-r--`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's not it. I don't know what else to suggest.